# how to set multiple color to an EditText with selecting words

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext

i have a Simple text editor app, that user can select words in EditText and change its color. 
for change color of selected word, i use this code:

```
    EditText edtText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
    SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(edtText.getText().toString());
    ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
    sb.setSpan(fcs, edtText.getSelectionStart(), edtText.getSelectionEnd(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    edtText.setText(sb);
```

this code works correctly, but i can not set multiple color to edit text. for example, i wrote "Hello how are you?" in EditText, and i want to colour "Hello" to blue and "How are you?" to red. when i select "Hello" and colour it blue, and then i select "how are you" and colour it red, the "Hello" word will be black. can any body help me? tahnks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HTML formatting:

```
 EditText.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlformatString))
```

Comment: i used HTML format, but this way change color of all similar words, for example if we write "hello my friend hello" and select second "hello", and colour it, first "hello" will colour too. can Guidance  me?

Comment: Edit the HTML while you want if the text is "hello my friend hello" and you want to color only the second hello the HTML text wiil be:"<font color="black">hello my friend </font></font color="red">hello</font>

Answer (score 0):

@user2139223: yes it is Correct, but in my app, user write a statement in edit text and can change it's color. i do not know what is statement and which word, selected. my problem is, with similar words, because with select one of them and colour that, all of them will be colour.
this is my code:

```
private void colorText(){
        EditText edtText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtText);
        String allText = Html.toHtml(edtText.getText());
        String selectedText = edtText.getText().toString().substring(edtText.getSelectionStart(), edtText.getSelectionEnd());
        String color = "#ff0000";
        String colorText = "<font color=\"" + color + "\">" + selectedText + "</font>";
        String text =allText.replace(selectedText, colorText);
        edtText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
}
```

whit click on a button, i call this method and change color of selected word to red.